# Which drive is an SSD drive on a D series Azure Cloud Service instance?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

Ideally, I'm looking for an article that **explicitly** says which disk(s) are ssd drives. At the moment I can see 3 disks. C, D and E. I used CristalDiskMark to test the speed of each disk and it turns out that D is by far the fastest so I'm assuming it is the SSD disk. The thing that does not make sense is that it is only 32GB on an a D12 VM and it should be 200GB.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this post: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/new-d-series-virtual-machine-sizes/, it is `D:\`. From this link:

> **On these new sizes, the temporary drive (D:\ on Windows, /mnt or
>   /mnt/resource on Linux) are local SSDs**. This high-speed local disk is
>   best used for workloads that replicate across multiple instances, like
>   MongoDB, or can leverage this high I/O disk for a local and temporary
>   cache, like SQL Server 2014's Buffer Pool Extensions. Note, these
>   drives are not guaranteed to be persistent. Thus, while physical
>   hardware failure is rare, when it occurs, the data on this disk may be
>   lost, unlike your OS disk and any attached durable disks that are
>   persisted in Azure Storage.

Comment: In my case the D disk is 32GB and this the bit that is confusing.